# AngularJS SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Not sure whats wrong with this but I keep getting this error on browser pointing to the closing parentheses of the IIFE. My Ajax call returns a large JSON from server side. Any help is appreciated.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('MenuCategoriesApp', [])
.controller ('MenuCategoriesController', MenuCategoriesController)
.service('MenuCategoriesService', MenuCategoriesService)
.constant('ApiBasePath', "http://sacchis-restaurant.herokuapp.com");

MenuCategoriesController.$inject = ['MenuCategoriesService'];

function MenuCategoriesController (MenuCategoriesService) {
    var menu = this;
    menu.logMenuItems = function (shortName) {
        var promise = MenuCategoriesService.getMenuForCategories(shortName);

        promise.then( function (response) {
            menu.categories = response.data;
        }).

        catch(function(){
        menu.errorText = 'something went terribly wrong!!'
    });
};  

MenuCategoriesService.$inject = ['$http', 'ApiBasePath'];

function MenuCategoriesService($http, ApiBasePath) {
    var service = this;
    service.getMenuForCategories = function (shortName) {
        var response = $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: (ApiBasePath + "/menu_items.json"),
            params : {
                category : shortName
                }
            });
        return response;
    };
};

})();
```

Comment: You've got an extra `};` in there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket at the end of menu.logMenuItems. See comment in code below:

```
function MenuCategoriesController (MenuCategoriesService) {
    var menu = this;
    menu.logMenuItems = function (shortName) {
        var promise = MenuCategoriesService.getMenuForCategories(shortName);

        promise.then( function (response) {
           menu.categories = response.data;
        }).

        catch(function(){
          menu.errorText = 'something went terribly wrong!!'
        });
    } // ** MISSING THIS CLOSING BRACKET **
};
```

Comment: Try cleaning up your files and use proper indentation before posting a question next time.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the closing '}' in the 'menu.logMenuItems' function.

It seems your indenting is a bit off in the closing `catch` promise method.
the closing `});` is actually for the `catch` call instead of the `menu.logMenuItems` function...

Try indenting all your code with 2 or 4 spaces, it will help you identifying next syntax errors :)

Also, configure your text editor to lint (validate) Javascript syntax!